# Can not get expand navigation to work on nav

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently have been experimenting with jquery in hopes to expand my knowledge. I have come across something odd though. I have a navigation where I want users to be able to expand it even further. However, everytime I click expand it opens up all menus rather than a specific one.

```
$('.expandicon').click(function(){
  if ( $('.nav-bucket-items').css('display') == 'none' )
    $('.nav-bucket-items').css('display','block');
  else
    $('.nav-bucket-items').css('display','none');
});
```

Here is the code I've used and here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/xajoujsx/

As you can see, when you click the expand + button, it opens up all navigation. I just wanted it to open up the one I click around. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why aren't you using accordion? it will make things much easier https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: I don't want to use a framework, I want to learn how to make my own work. That is, aside from jquery of course.

Comment: But you're already using JQuery, Accordion is part of JQuery. You just need to include the JQuery UI

Answer (score 2):

From inside the click handler you can refer to `.nav-bucket-items` using:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.nav-bucket-items')
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xajoujsx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The code currently performs it on all elements with class .nav-bucket.

One option is to  only apply to the immediate items for the parent.

```
$('.expandicon').click(function() {
  var $ref = $($(this).parent().parent()).find('.nav-bucket-items')
  if ($ref.css('display') == 'none')
    $ref.css('display', 'block');
  else
    $ref.css('display', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things going on here, first, you're targeting all of the elements when you do `$('.nav-bucket-items')`

If you run that in your console you should see a list of elements rather than a single one, so what we want to do is target the parent, and then find the sibling, we also want to target the element link not the icon so that way the user can click the entire element to expand.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/dg4z271m/1/

Answer (score 0):

I love it when I can learn someone more about their code than just fix the code for the sake of answering the question.
First, let me start by saying you don't need the .css('display','block'); to show or hide elements because .show() en .hide() does that for you. Amazing isn't it?
So, now we are left with this.

```
$('.expandicon').click(function(){
    if ( $('.nav-bucket-items').css('display') == 'none' )
        $('.nav-bucket-items').show();
    else
        $('.nav-bucket-items').hide();
});
```

But now we still have the problem of the multi-expanding menu. This is because you show (or hide) alle elements with the class '.nav-bucket-items' We just wan't the ones that are family of the .expandicon we've clicked! You can do that with $(this). You can use $(this) to traverse from the element you've clicked. Lets see.

```
$('.expandicon').click(function(){
    if ( $('.nav-bucket-items').css('display') == 'none' )
        $(this).parent().next('.nav-bucket-items')
    else
        $(this).parent().next('.nav-bucket-items')
});
```

When you use this, it will all be working as you wished. But we can do better than this! We can make it shorter, better and cleaner. We don't have to check if .nav-bucket-items is visible. Nope.

```
$('.expandicon').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('.nav-bucket-items').toggle();
});
```

Did you see what happened? We just changed that whole bunch of code to one line that just toggles the element. So it will hide it when its shown and it will show when its hidden! If you really want some fancy effects, you could use slideToggle() or fadeToggle() instead of .toggle(). I updated your JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xajoujsx/3/